# NSMutableData allocation performance

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c++, core-foundation

I'm wondering why NSMutableData allocation and freeing is so incredibly slow.

I wanted to test unique_ptr+new[] vs malloc()/free() allocation/freeing performance, found they are just the same and eventually tried to compare with NSMutableData to use as a raw bytes buffer.

Result are seems to be quite strange - I wasn't even able to wait for NSMutableData cycle to finish and even worse, app was consuming a LOT more memory than with raw C/C++ memory allocation.
I know that all this CoreFoundation/ObjectiveC mechanics requires some overhead to work, but this seems to be too much. What am I missing? Thanks.

Here's the test code (compile as ObjectiveC++):

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

// dummy function in other compilation unit to fool optimizer:
// void Fake(void *v){}
void Fake(void *v);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const size_t sizes_amount = 256;
    const size_t runs = /* 16 * */ 1024*1024;
    size_t sizes[sizes_amount];

    mt19937 mt((random_device())());
    uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, 1024*1024);
    for(auto &i: sizes)
        i = dist(mt); // allocating from 0 to 1M bytes

    // test malloc/free and c pointers
    auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < runs; ++i) {
        void *v = malloc(sizes[i % sizes_amount]);
        Fake(v);
        free(v);
    }

    // test unique_ptr + new uint8_t[]
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < runs; ++i) {
        unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> v(new uint8_t[ sizes[i % sizes_amount] ]);
        Fake(v.get());
        v.reset();
    }

    // test NSMutableData
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < runs; ++i) {
        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:sizes[i % sizes_amount]];
        Fake(data.mutableBytes);
    }

    auto t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    printf("malloc/free + c pointers: %lld\n", duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count());
    printf("new/detele + unique_ptr: %lld\n", duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count());
    printf("NSMutableData: %lld\n", duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3 - t2).count());
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
For pure CoreFoundation everything seems to be reasonable (something like 50x penalty of speed, which is ok for such synthetic test, and equal memory consumption):

```
for(int i = 0; i < runs; ++i) {
    CFMutableDataRef data = CFDataCreateMutable(0, sizes[i % sizes_amount]);
    CFDataSetLength(data, sizes[i % sizes_amount]);
    Fake(CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(data));
    CFRelease(data);
}
```

This difference is weird since NSMutableData and CFMutableDataRef are toll-free bridged and (in theory) can use the same internal mechanics.

Comment: what happens if you call "`data = nil`" after you do your call to "`Fake(data.mutableBytes)`"?

Comment: just the same - ARC will do it's job anyway when visibility scope ends.

Comment: Note that your test is inconsistent about initializing the allocations, which will be a big advantage in favor of the ones that do not initialize.

Comment: @GregParker thanks for pointing it out. Indeed, after inserting memset(..) numbers becomes quite comparable, with penalty like 5-10%. Sadly there's no way to allocate CFData memory without zeroing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableData` objects are autoreleased which means they are never freed, because there is no pool in place (or it is never popped). This is why it takes so much memory, which is why it is so slow. CoreFoundation functions, on the other hand, do not employ autorelease mechanism, that is why they behave differently here, even though the same code is used internally in both `NSMutableData` and `CFMutableData`.

You need to wrap the loop's body into `@autoreleasepool {}` (or as @Chuck pointed out, do manual `alloc`/`init`/`release`).

Comment: Or just use alloc instead of dataWithLength:.

Comment: That's it, thanks! So after visibility scope ends ARC sets refcount to zero and something like -(void) dealloc is called, but memory for object itself is still there before autorelease pool draining?

Comment: @Migun ARC does not do anything for objects that are already autoreleased, at least in release builds, because there is no need. It will only release owned objects (e.g. using `alloc`/`init`) when scope ends.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. There is no reason that there must be any autorelease if this is under ARC.

Comment: @newacct: It doesn't *have* to be autoreleased – that is, if all methods were suddenly defined as returning owning references, ARC would work just fine – but as a matter of fact it *is* autoreleased. ARC retains the memory management semantics of MRR code. So this answer is a correct description of reality.

Comment: @Chuck: No, the methods do not have to be defined as returning owning references for what I say to be true. ARC has a mechanism where a normal (non-returning-owning-reference) method can hand off ownership of the returned value to its calling function, without autorelease and retain. If you write a normal (non-returning-owning-reference) method right now in ARC, which creates a new object and returns it, and you assign it to a variable in the calling function (also in ARC), there is no autorelease. You can try it.

Comment: @newacct: But that isn't what happens here. You're talking about what could happen — an optimization applied by the compiler in ARC mode — rather than what does happen in the case in question. My point is that this answer is factually correct.

Comment: @Chuck: And how do you (or the answerer) possibly know "what happens here"? Have you examined the assembly of the NSData methods in the Foundation binary? Are you just guessing empirically based on profiling repeated runs? My point is that this answer is just an unsupported assertion not backed by any documentation or language knowledge. Plus how the Foundation library is compiled is an internal implementation detail and can change from version to version. You cannot rely on it. This answer can, at best, only claim to seem to be true for a particular version of Foundation.

Comment: @newacct: I could do extensive tests to prove whether or not it is autoreleased, but what would be the point? It's not an extraordinary claim to say that Foundation autoreleased something — anyone who has done serious Cocoa programming will have seen  autoreleased objects before — and the hypothesis "The object is autoreleased" fits the data very well. Unless you have a good reason to believe something else is going on here, I don't understand why you're objecting so strongly. You're right that the answer might change, but that's true of everything (e.g. "Is `someDictionary[@"aKey"]` valid?").

Comment: @Chuck: Prior to ARC, when you create a new object in a non-returns-retained method and return it (whether your method or Foundation or whatever), and it is not cached anywhere, it must be autoreleased, simply because someone must have a strong reference to it. However, this changed with ARC. Now, when you write such a method that returns a newly-created object in your code in ARC, it is usually not autoreleased. So past experience is not useful on this point. Since this behavior changed with ARC in your code, it is very likely to change in Foundation too.

Comment: @newacct: That is the case sometimes. It's an optimization that the compiler can apply in many cases, but not all. And I don't know that Foundation is even compiled with ARC — in fact, I am pretty skeptical of it, especially given that it must do some things that ARC forbids (e.g. call `dealloc`).

Comment: @newacct The thing you are talking about is just an optimization, which may or may not happen. Even when it is available, not all autoreleases will be removed; enabling ARC certainly does not mean that nothing will ever be autoreleased. Expecting this ARC optimization to always happen is what would be relying on implementation details of one particular compiler, configuration and framework version. The old memory management rules still hold and one must reason about code like this optimization is not there.

Comment: @hamstergene: Nothing you said contradicts anything I said. If you do not want to "rely on implementation details", you cannot say there will be an autorelease here.

Comment: @newacct If a method returns a new object and its name does not begin with `new`, `init` or `copy`, the object will be returned autoreleased. `dataWithLength:` by this convention, returns autoreleased object. This is very basic rule and it existed long before inventing ARC, and enabling ARC does not change it, though sometimes the optimizer may indeed remove some autorelease calls.

Comment: @hamstergene: We are going around in circles, but basically you are agreeing with what I said but maybe you mean a different thing when you say "autoreleased". The ARC specification (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values) says that for the type of method you mention above, "In the worst case, this may involve an autorelease, but callers must not assume that the value is actually in the autorelease pool." "involve an autorelease" and the value being put into the autorelease pool, is what I think people mean when they say an object is "autoreleased".